# Ubuntu 22.10 freezes frequently

Tags: suspend, freeze, 22.10

I have recently upgraded to 22.10 from 22.04, and it often freezes. The screen freezes, and the keyboard do not work. The mouse keeps working only. I am not getting any logic behind it.
The highlighted are the last few logs I could see before a force shutdown occurred.

[image]

One more thing, I mostly keep my laptop suspended, and after the upgrade, it does not boot back sometimes, and the screen stays black.

Are the issues related? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr : try the following :

- If you’re using a Wayland session, try X11 instead (click the cog on the login screen)
- If you’re already using X11, set your *Nvidia Prime* configuration to `intel` (`prime-select intel` + reboot) (doesn’t work on Wayland afaik)

The only possibly related message I see is “Failed to grab modeset ownership”, but it shouldn’t be a problem. I suppose you have an Optimus dual GPU setup, and the Nvidia driver just doesn’t control modeset because the dGPU’s driver does. I’m frequently in a similar situation when I play games.

That being said, I noticed some freezes on the login screen since I upgraded to 22.10 too (didn’t have this on 22.04, and not before either), even when the Nvidia driver is unloaded, i.e. in a pure dGPU configuration, but that didn’t bother me too much since it’s the login screen only. Note that the login screen is a *Wayland* session by default, and I kept it like that, but I always open my user sessions as *X-Window* sessions, so that could be it : do you use *Wayland*, or *X-Window* ? You can choose by clicking the cog on the login screen, on the bottom right iirc.

Considering Wayland is supposed to be the future, I suppose it should be addressed at some point, but imo it seems to be lacking right now, both conceptually and technically… but that’s not the subject here.

I bet you’re on Wayland, but if you’re using X11, what’s your *Nvidia Prime* configuration, `nvidia` or `on-demand` ? You can check with `prime-select query`. I remember I had problems with `on-demand` a long time ago, and decided to use `nvidia` instead, but maybe that’s been addressed. Maybe you could try switching to `intel`, effectively disabling the use of the Nvidia dGPU (`prime-select intel` and reboot), and see how it goes. *Nvidia Prime* isn’t supported on Wayland, however, even on Wayland, setting to `intel` will blacklist the `nvidia` module and may have some impact.